# Why doesn't wminput work?

Tags: 10.10

I have even tried installing wminput from source, but uinput refuses to load on my system.  I even loaded the kernel module manually. How can I alleviate this?

Comment: You'll need to describe exactly what goes wrong, otherwise, we won't have a clue what your problem actually is. Please edit your question and add some detailed information, like error messages and what you've done that caused them.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.